# Can "memorable" and "easy to remember" be interchanged?

Tags: word-usage

This is the definition of `memorable` in the dictionary https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3Amemorable

> memorable: worth remembering or easily remembered, especially because
>   of being special or unusual.

Ex: *this victory was one of the most memorable of his career*

Can I change the above sentence to *this victory was one of the easiest to remember of his career*?

Ex2: *This story is memorable*

Can I change it to *This story is easy to remember*?

Comment: No ! ! ! ! ! ! !

Comment: Grammatically and literally yes but you lose the nuance of the anticipated nostalgia.   No one looks back on the good old days just because they were easy to remember.

Comment: Facts are easy to remember. Emotional events are memorable.

Comment: @Mynamite Agreed. In addition, "easy to remember" is for things you deliberately try to commit to memory, in the hope that you'll recall them when you need to; a memorable event can be one which comes to mind without you trying.

Answer (score 2):

It's all about connotation:

A first kiss is memorable.

9-1-1 is easy to remember.